# Is there anyway to use HangFire.Console() with NLog?

Tags: c#, windows, service, console, hangfire

I've been able to set a Windows Service using Hangfire, but I want to Configure NLog to print using the HangFire.Console()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should understand is that HangFire.Console works within the context of a method call, it's not scoped to the entire application.

That being said, you should be able to write your own [Nlog target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target) implementation that uses the Hangfire.Console extension methods.

The more complicated aspect of this would be to get the Hangfire PerformContext instance in your implementation, and being able to handle multiple PerformContext instances. Also note that you don't have the context until Hangfire invokes your method...so no logging until then.